# How to pull calculated Measures into "New Table" in PBI

Tags: parameters, powerbi, simulation, measure

i would like to create a simulation in PBI, i'm using norm.inv and i need to define mean and sigma, these parameters are calculated depending some filters in my page (# of years, states, etc...). My problem is that when i create "New table" with the code and i set the parameters (mean and Sigma equal to my measures) that values are pulling the data without any filter, i mean have the value for whole data. I'm trying to simulate the # of days with temperature < x° in some season. where ZZ_Y is the sum of that days
**How can i create a dynamic table that could be able to pull new parameters each time that my filters change?**

```
ZZ_Y average per Year_ = 
AVERAGEX(KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Historical_Data'[Year_])), CALCULATE([ZZ_Y]))

ZZ_Y variance per Year_ = 
VARX.P(KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Historical_Data'[Year_])), CALCULATE([ZZ_Y]))


Simulation = 
var Mean_ = [ZZ_Y average per Year_]
var Sigma_ = power([ZZ_Y variance per Year_], .5)
Return
SELECTCOLUMNS(
            GENERATESERIES(.001, 1, .001),
               "_Value" , [Value] ,
               "_Index" , norm.inv([Value] , Mean_, Sigma_),
                "Mean", Mean_,
                "Sigma", Sigma_,
                "Y_1" , norm.inv(RAND(), Mean_, Sigma_),
                "Y_2" , norm.inv(RAND(), Mean_, Sigma_),
                "Y_3" , norm.inv(RAND(), Mean_, Sigma_)
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Power BI does not allow calculated tables based on dynamic filtering to be part of the model. This is because calculated tables and columns are only computed once when the data is loaded and the model of tables and relationships is set up and therefore cannot be responsive to any slicers or filters.

However, you *can* use calculated tables like these within a measure. For example, the following should be a valid measure (assuming I don't have any syntax errors):

```
Simulation =
VAR Mean_ = [ZZ_Y average per Year_]
VAR Sigma_ = POWER ( [ZZ_Y variance per Year_], 0.5 )
VAR Matrix =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( .001, 1, .001 ),
        "_Value", [Value],
        "_Index", NORM.INV ( [Value], Mean_, Sigma_ ),
        "Mean", Mean_,
        "Sigma", Sigma_,
        "Y_1", NORM.INV ( RAND (), Mean_, Sigma_ ),
        "Y_2", NORM.INV ( RAND (), Mean_, Sigma_ ),
        "Y_3", NORM.INV ( RAND (), Mean_, Sigma_ )
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX ( Matrix, [Y_1] + [Y_2] + [Y_3] )
```